# Determine current stage in smart contract

Tags: solidity

Suppose that i have stages with date range and discount as follow.

stage1 -> 2019-01-01 - 2019-02-02 -> 40% discount 
stage2 -> 2019-03-03 - 2019-04-04 -> 30% discount 
stage3 -> 2019-05-05 - 2019-06-06 -> 20% discount

How can i check that the token is mintable at current date.
**Note:**
- might have gap date during each stage
- no looping as it require high gas cost
- no manual set minting stage by owner
- logic must be implemented inside smart contract only (no external oracle to determine current stage)

I couldn't find a way that satisfy the 4 condition above.
But this seems to be a very common use case in ico.
Hope someone can enlighten me on this.

```
struct stage {
  uint256 startDate;
  uint256 endDate;
  uint8 discount;
}

mapping(bytes32 => stage) stageMap;


function getCurrentStage() private view returns (bytes32) {
   // what logic should be done here?
   // Note:
   // No storing the entire stages in array and loop through it to compare the date
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic-length array and store the stages in **reverse chronological order**. The first item in the array should be the final stage, the final item is the first stage.

You then always look at the last item in the array to see if the stage is active.  If `now > endDate`, delete the final entry and look at the new final entry.  Deleting gives you a gas refund, so any iteration from this process will reduce overall costs rather than increasing them.

Here is a minimal example for how to add the stages and as well as check the currently active stage:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.10;

contract MultiStage {

    struct stage {
      uint256 startDate;
      uint256 endDate;
      uint8 discount;
    }

    stage[] saleStages;

    function addStage(uint256 _start, uint256 _end, uint8 _discount) external {
        require(_start < _end);
        uint256 _length = saleStages.length;
        if (_length > 0) {
             // ensure reverse chronological order when adding new stages
             require(saleStages[_length-1].startDate > _end);
        }
        saleStages.push(stage(_start, _end, _discount));
    }

    function getCurrentStage() private returns (uint256 _index) {
        _index = saleStages.length;
        while (_index > 0 && now > saleStages[_index-1].endDate) {
            _index--;
        }
        if (_index != saleStages.length) {
            saleStages.length = _index;
        }
        require(_index > 0, "Final stage has ended");
        return _index - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, iteration wouldn't be horrible because it would be limited to the number of stages that will exist. You could still work it out without a loop.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Stages {

    struct Stage {
        uint first;
        uint last;
    }

    Stage[] public stages;

    function appendStage(uint first, uint last) public {
        Stage memory s = Stage({
            first: first,
            last: last
        });
        stages.push(s);
    }

    function isStage(uint i) public view returns(bool) {
        return block.number >= stages[i].first && block.number <= stages[i].last;
    }

    /*
    you can go ....

    if(isStage(3) { ...

    */
}
```

Hope it helps.